# Define the structure of a Object in advance

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb, object

I reuse a project [About Node and Passport](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/upgrading-our-easy-node-authentication-series-to-expressjs-4-0) that use mongodb, where a schema is defined as the following, in a user.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local : {
        email : String,
        password : String,
    },
    facebook : {
        id : String,
        token : String,
        email : String,
        name : String
    },
    twitter : {
        id : String,
        token : String,
        displayName : String,
        username : String
    },
    google : {
        id : String,
        token : String,
        email : String,
        name : String
    }
});
module.exports = ('User', userSchema);
```

As i'm using mysql, I'm trying to keep that object structure, for the rest of the code.

So how can I define an object like this, to be able to instantiate it, to then work on it like :

```
var User = require('../app/models/user');

var newUser = new User();
newUser.local.email = "babab";
newUser.local.password = "bababab";
```

Probably a trival question, but I'm a bit lost with the javascript object handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @kirinthos, various solution appears. I select the most basic one (I think), but comment and improvement are welcome:

The object definition

```
module.exports = Object({
    id : String,
    local : {
        email : String,
        password : String,
    },
    facebook : {
        id : String,
        token : String,
        email : String,
        name : String
    },
    twitter : {
        id : String,
        token : String,
        displayName : String,
        username : String
    },
    google : {
        id : String,
        token : String,
        email : String,
        name : String
    }
});
```

The object instancitation :

```
var User = require('../app/models/user');

var newUser = Object.create(User);
newUser.local.email = "babab";
newUser.local.password = "bababab";
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

What you're looking for is javascript prototypes

edit: here's an article for node specifically, 
http://howtonode.org/prototypical-inheritance